# Jquery selecting td by element

Tags: jquery

I have 3 columns in a table & I have list of records in table. In first column i have checkbox.
If the checkbox is checked i want to add some text in 3rd or last `td`. I get the data in `Array Objects`, so i iterate through it.

```
jq.each(masterData, function (index, item) {
     jq('.fields[value=' + item.FieldValue1 + ']').find(':last-child').text(item.FieldValue3);
     jq('.fields[value=' + item.FieldValue1 + ']').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

What i want is If the checkbox in the first column is checked then i have to add some value in last td.

The above code doesn't work. What is the solution?

Comment: It's not working, because you don't even have `if` to check if checkox is checked...

Comment: @Justinas Firstly i have unchecked all the checkboxes, on the basis of `masterData` i am checking them one by one.

Comment: what is the reason for minus points?

Comment: Ok i got the answer myself... `jq('.fields[value="' + item.FieldValue1 + '"]').closest('tr').children('td').eq(2).text(item.FieldValue3);` Just replaced this line.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing condition to check if checkbox is checked:

```
jq.each(masterData, function (index, item) {
    if (jq('.fields[value=' + item.FieldValue1 + ']').is(':checked')) {
        jq('.fields[value=' + item.FieldValue1 + ']').find(':last-child').text(item.FieldValue3);
    }

    // this line makes no sense for me. It will always makes checkbox checked...
    jq('.fields[value=' + item.FieldValue1 + ']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: I am checking the checkbox from the above `foreach` as all checkboxes are unchecked at first.